# How to compile Android from source?

Tags: android, compilation

I want to compile the source code of my android phone. I have an Alcatel OT6010D Android 4.1.1 . Source code for my device is available from Vendor. Here is the link: 
 http://sourceforge.net/projects/alcatel/files/OT_6010D_20130509.tar.xz/download

But I don't know what to do with this source how to compile it etc.
If anyone could guide me, it would be so nice.

Just to for orientation I am an Embedded system programmer so if someone could tell me some starting point it would be a nice start for me.

Thanks

Comment: the AOSP is the best place to start: https://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html

Answer (score 1):

You can start at [The Android Source Code](http://source.android.com/source/index.html).

At [Downloading and Building](http://source.android.com/source/building.html), you have subitems [Building the System](http://source.android.com/source/building-running.html), which describes the common parts, [Building for devices](http://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html), describing specific information to individual devices and [Building Kernels](http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html), if you just want to build the kernel alone.